# Can an input type be updated after an interval in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I change input type after an interval since the view has initialized.
So after a set timer ( 5 sec here) I want to change the input type value.

HTML

```
<input type = {{this.inputType}} ></input>
```

TS

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        interval(5000).subscribe(() => { 
          this.inputType =  this.inputType === 'text' ? 'number' : 'number';
          console.log(this.inputType);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Obvious question is what happens when you try it?

Comment: Input type in html doesnt change but console prints out number

Comment: This is not gonna work and you can do simply add two input as text and number, based on the inputType you can switch the input tag (you can if-else in the DOM)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input [type]="inputType === 'number' ? 'number' : 'text'" ></input>
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. Type remains text for the input tag

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try again.